# conditional probability question

Tags: probability

> to get a license, one's need to pass a 3 stages exam.
>   
>   If one's fail in one stage he can not continue to the next stage.
>   
>   The probability he will pass the first stage is $0.9$, if he passed the first stage, the probability he will pass the second test is $0.8$.
>    if he passed the first and second test the probability he will pass the last one is $0.7$
>   
>   1.What is the probability that he will pass the exam?
>   
>   2. If it is known that he did not pass all the stages, what is the conditional probability he failed the in the second stage?

1. does $0.9*0.8*0.7=0.504$ can be used if it is a conditional probability?
2. how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, your approach is correct: You can multiply them together since one will only happen if the other too. If he passes the first one with $0,9$ chance, then he has $0,8$ chance to pass the second, and $0,7$ to pass the third: $0,9*0,8*0,7$ is the correct answer.

For the second part, if he failed there are several cases:

- He failed at the first part: $1-0,9=0,1$.
- He failed at the second part, then he had to succeed in the fist part: $0,9*(1-0,8)=0,9*0,2=0,18$.(This was the question)
- He failed at the third part, then he had to succeed in the first two part: $0,9*0,8*(1-0,7)=0,216$.

Comment: I found the answer to 2. is it $\frac{0.9\cdot 0.2}{1-0.504}$ why should we divide in the total chance to fail?

Comment: I don't know why is it divided with it. It is as simple as it looks: If he fails in the second part, then he has to succeed in the first and fail in second, that must be correct.

Comment: here is the full answer http://i.imgur.com/C3tlHoa.png what does it mean?

Comment: I am not sure that this answer is correct. :)

Comment: the end result is true according to the book, so it seems that it is

Comment: Maybe because you wrote: it is known that he did not pass all the stages. If that is surely known, maybe that's why we need to divide with $1-0,504$, but about that I am not sure. :)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is correct due to the equation

$$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P_A(B)P_{A\cap B}C$$

This follows from $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P_A(B)$$, (first
insert $A$ and $B$ and then, insert  $A\cap B$ and $C$)

The text says that the desired probability is indeed $0.9\times 0.8\times 0.7$
because the conditioned probabilities are exactly those in the formula.